# Where to save passwords while integrating with External APIs

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, passwords, integration, credentials

We are trying to integrate with an external API using a `C#`application. The creators have given us credentials that we use to connect to their API using `HTTPClient`.
It all works fine but I am not able to assess what is the best place to save these credentials. Certainly `AppConfig` is the least safe, then other options are DB or `EnvironmentVariables` ?

I have never worked with such issues hence want to check what are the possible and best options to save sensitive information that is configurable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to store credentials in an independent safe place and your application should ask for those credentials when you start the application.

For example, you can use conjur and summon. Wrap up your binary by the summon and provide EnvironmentVariables only to this process of your application.

https://www.conjur.org/

https://github.com/cyberark/summon

https://github.com/cyberark/summon-conjur

This is a big topic, if you would like to ask for a specific problem, do it!